# iPhone Swift Bluetooth Devices in Range

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I need some help unfortunately I don't have any code I want to get the range of the connected bluetooth device using Swift and iOS device.
Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the (exact)  distance between the bluetooth device and your phone. Because there are too many factors which affect any calculations.